# Positioning in CSS - Wrong alignment

Tags: html, css

I’m having a hard time here. I have got two individual pieces of code working nicely but when I put them together there it all goes wrong.

[Here is my WYSIWYG code](http://jsfiddle.net/bzjW7/)

[Here is when I try and try to put it in my field box](http://jsfiddle.net/Vh26b/3/)

```
<div class="field_box">
  <label field_id="None" for="position">Test2</label>
  <div class="fieldwrapper">
    <textarea class="uEditorCustom" name="textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a few things but haven't had any luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What have you tried? What should this code do? What is the relevance of the HTML code you've posted? You're asking us to parse a lot of code here with little to go on.

Comment: May I recommend ckeditor? Great WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: I want the WYSIWYG editor to sit correctly in the grey box, like the input field above it does. CKeditor looks alright but it is so fat and bloated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. But the editor is throwing CSS into the mix that's not playing nicely with your own.

http://jsfiddle.net/sCATj/

I added these two lines to the bottom of the CSS, and I think the results (at least in FF) are what you're after.

```
.fieldwrapper {overflow:hidden;}
.uEditor { float:right }    ​
```